# AngularJS Google Maps API Async loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

Hello I try to load the google maps api asynchronously in AngularJS following this link:http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module RegisterClientModule  due to:
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure')
```

my code(Please note: I just started with AngularJS 2-3 days ago, I guess my mistake is easy to fix once I fully understand why this is not working):

```
var module = angular.module('RegisterClientModule', [])
.config(['$routeProvider', function    config($routeProvider,uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/registerclient', {
    controller: 'RegisterClientController',
    templateUrl: '/scripts/modules/RegisterClientModule/registerClientView.html'
});
uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
    v: '3.17',
    libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
});
}]);

module.controller('RegisterClientController', ['$scope', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi ) {
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
    console.log("Google maps api loaded");
});
$scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
console.log("Google maps api provider:"+uiGmapGoogleMapApi );

}]);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You missed to include `uiGmapgoogle-maps` in you app module. That will make available the `uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider` & all other API of Google map.

```
var module = angular.module('RegisterClientModule', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
```

Comment: I have added it, actually when I don't try to load it async the module works just fine, the problem only occurs when I try to configure the module to load async.

Comment: ever find your answer? Having the same problem and i added the uiGmapgoogle-maps module